# Material Design : Space between inline inputs

Tags: forms, input, google-materials-design

[Material Design](https://material.google.com/) doesn't specify any space between inline text inputs.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Do I assume the 9dp spacing would apply?

Comment: http://materializecss.com/forms.html has some inline forms

Comment: This is a question about design, not user experience.

Comment: The experience comes from being able to discern which form fields (inline) are related or not. For a first/last name, close inputs might make sense, but if theyre unrelated (say address/phone) then their close proximity might be found to be confusing....

Comment: Examples for @Rob

Angular inline inputs: http://imgur.com/uRLAWTb

Google MD inline inputs: http://imgur.com/CrZpz0P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the space between inline [text inputs](https://material.google.com/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-labels) is equal to the padding below the input text (with the  divider included): 16dp.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Great - but its def not specified. 

FYI, between the Google spec site, and Angular spec sites - they differ...

Im just finding it confusing when people are promoting their specs as "google material" when they differ from the spec...

Comment: Its sad that we visually have to guess - but I agree :)

Comment: I agree that it is a little confusing in this case, @KyLane, but it is our job to design some elements and not just follow some rules! :)

Answer (score -1):

I personally find that using bitwise increments to be rather suiting.

For example my gaps between inputs is about 8 or 16 pixels thick. I would load your site on a mobile device to see how it feels and then see how it looks in desktops before settling on anything. (12 may be a good in-between as well)

Try these out and see how it looks. It might not feel right if you use wider or smaller margins for your entire webpage. Try to keep to a "norm" for your site, think of it as an in-site standard, for margins between items.

Don't be mistaken, I do not mean that you should try to use the same margins between all items, only that you should find a set to use and stick to. For example I use: 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 24, and 32 pixel margins between items in my site and that is it. This way spacing is used as a building tool and keeps a pleasant flow throughout the site experience!

A good practice of site-wide uniformity will make it more appealing and user friendly. Both to thier thumbs/cursors and eyes!